# How to properly export SWIG typedef from within class declaration?

Tags: c++, ocaml, swig

I'm using SWIG, and in a header file `evidence.h`, I have the following:

```
namespace dai {
    class Evidence {
        public:
            typedef std::map<Var, size_t> Observation;
    };
}
```

And in a swig interface file `dai.i`, I have the following:

```
//The types are defined in both swig and the output cxx file...
%include "../include/dai/evidence.h"
%include "../include/dai/var.h"
#include "../include/dai/evidence.h"


//namespace std {
%{
   typedef std::map<Var, size_t> Observation;
%}
//  %template(Observation) map<Var, size_t>;
//}
typedef std::map<Var, size_t> Observation;
%template(VecObservation) std::vector<dai::Evidence::Observation>;
```

I believe that Var is making it's way correctly to the generated cxx file and ml files, so I won't go into that part. Just what I'm having an issue with, which is adding an item to the VecObservation template that I've declared. In a test.ml file, I have the following:

```
let observation = new_Observation C_void in
let observations = new_VecObservation C_void in
let _ = (invoke observations) "push_back" observation in ()
```

And I am getting an error that corresponds to the `push_back` line:

> (Failure "No appropriate conversion found.")

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, typedef and rename and template each do different things for SWIG regarding the output interface modules and the C/++ code, and getting things working isn't exactly a one to one mapping from the C/++ code to the swig interface. So despite the fact that the Observation type in the actual header is typedef'd, what worked was using the %template swig macro/language/term.

In any case, the issue is that in the C code, every template or type corresponds to a enum or declaration that is used in a kind of mapping of an array. This array is used to facilitate the homogenous type interface by making the type a number that is carried around with the instance, and then used in the lookup.

Therefore the, "No appropriate conversion found." error was actually the dynamic typing looking for an identical type but with some different SWIG jargon for the ultimate name. If you choose to template Observation, but then use anything other except for exactly what you templated before, it doesn't map. So, you have to be careful with your swig interface files.

This worked:

```
%template(Observation) std::map<Var, size_t>;
%template(VecObservation) std::vector<std::map<Var, size_t>>;
```